# Node.js - Import Package Issue - Not a Function

Tags: node.js

Using node v12.9.0 on macOS Mojave, have the following project structure (with app being the root folder):

```
app
   \ 
    utils.js
    app.js
```

utils.js

```
console.log('utils.js')

const add = function(a ,b) {
    return a + b
}

module.exports = add
```

app.js

```
const add = require('./utils.js')

const sum = add(4, -2)

console.log(sum)
```

Tried running this:

```
node app.js
```

Error:

```
app/app.js:3
const sum = add(4, -2)
        ^

TypeError: add is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/devuser/app/app.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Comment: are you in the `app` folder? it seems you're in the root, you need to run as `node .\app\app.js` ... [my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEOqA.png)

Comment: Do you have any other export functions in utils.js? If so,sum needs to be imported -const {add} = require('./utils.js')

Comment: Use `function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}` in utils.js

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

utils.js

```
const add = function(a ,b) {
    return a + b
}

module.exports = {
    add : add
}
```

app.js

```
const utils = require('./utils.js')

const sum = utils.add(4, -2)

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually works now using my original code inside both the Integrated Terminal that Visual Studio Code provides and the native macOS Terminal.

Now it just prints:

```
2
```

Don't know why it was had a TypeError earlier?

Am new to node.js so I can't comment on what changed?